# Why printing Array of String in c not providing same output?

Tags: c, arrays, string, character

When the last character matched to the first character of next element of array the output given the last character repeated. What is the reason and what should be the solution ?

[image: Left side is program right side is output]

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  int i ;

  char fact_char[13][2] = {"I", "IV", "V", "IX", "X", "XL", "L", "XC", "C", "CD", "D", "CM", "M"};

  for(i = 0; i < 13; i++){
    printf("%s\n", fact_char[i]);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
I
IVV
V
IXX
X
XLL
L
XCC
C
CDD
D
CMM
M
```

Comment: ,... or use `printf("%.2s\n", fact_char[i]);` to  limit printing to 2 characters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Strings in c are null terminated. To represent "IV", you're actually storing 'I','V' and '\0' in memory. When you're printing a two character string, printf is going to keep writing until it finds the next null terminator in memory, which happens to be in the next (single character) string.

To fix this, just make it

fact_char[13][**3**]

Answer (score 5):

Your array declarations don't allow room for the null terminators of the 2-letter strings. Change it to

```
char fact_char[13][3]
```

Using `%s` format to print a `char` array that doesn't have a null terminator results in undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

`printf("%s\n", fact_char[i]);` expects `fact_char[i]` to be a *string*.

> A *string* is a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null character.  C18

`fact_char[11]` is not a *string* as it lacks a *null character*.  It is only `'C'`, `'M'`.

Either allow more space with `fact_char[13][3]` or print with a width limit.  The following will stop printing after 2 characters or until a *null character* is encountered.  `fact_char[11]` will still not be a *string* as it lacks a *null character*.

```
printf("%.2s\n", fact_c[i]); // limit print width
```